# Reflection + AOP - advice not intercepted when calling method via invoke

Tags: java, reflection, spring-aop

Via Reflection:

```
Class c = Class.forName("mypackage.DiodeService");
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("blink");
Object t = c.newInstance();
Object o = m.invoke(t);
```

Method from DiodeService is invoked:

```
@ValueGreaterThan
public void blink(){
    log.info("Diode service: blink()");
}
```

On the annotation @ValueGreaterThan is listening aspect:

```
@Around(value = "mypackage.CommonJoinPointConfig.valueGreaterThanAspect())") public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    log.info("Value greater than aspect {}", joinPoint); }
```

**BUT: The around advice is never intercepted, when calling method by "invoke".**

Around advice is intercepted normally, when calling by `diodeService.blink()`

Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring AOP is based on **runtime weaving** due to the **proxy-based nature** of the Spring framework. This means the target bean is a Spring-managed bean. The bean is turned into a **proxy** during Spring runtime.

In the case where the `DiodeService` is a **Spring proxy** (managed by Spring), the Spring AOP will work normally as intended, i.e., the advice **will be intercepted** for any calls to `blink`.

The advice around `blink` **will never be intercepted** if `DiodeService` is **instantiated directly** and not via Spring. This is the case when you are instantiating `DiodeService` by calling `newInstance`,

`Object t = c.newInstance()`